# Android - Error says The type new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){} must implement the inherited

Tags: java, android

Getting error as 
    ***"The type new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method DialogInterface.OnClickListener.onClick(DialogInterface, int)"***

```
 package com.example.detectinternetconnection;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class AndroidDetect extends Activity {

// flag for Internet connection status
Boolean isInternetPresent = false;

// Connection detector class
ConnectionDetector cd;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button btnStatus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_check);

    // creating connection detector class instance
    cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

    /**
     * Check Internet status button click event
     * */
    btnStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // get Internet status
            isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();

            // check for Internet status
            if (isInternetPresent) {
                // Internet Connection is Present
                // make HTTP requests
                 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AndroidDetectInternet.this);
                    builder.setMessage("You have network connection.")
                           .setTitle("Internet Connection")
                             .setCancelable(false);
                    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                    alert.setButton("Continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){ 
                          // Do call some activity. Do what you wish to;
                            startActivity(new Intent(AndroidDetectInternet.this,MainActivity2.class));
                           }
                          }); 
                    alert.show();
            }

             else {
                // Internet connection is not present
                // Ask user to connect to Internet
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AndroidDetectInternet.this);
                builder.setMessage("You need a network connection to use this application. Please turn on mobile network or Wi-Fi in Settings.")
                       .setTitle("No Internet Connection")
                         .setCancelable(false);
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.setButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                         //close the program
                         AndroidDetectInternet.this.finish();
               }
            });
                // Showing Alert Message
                alert.show();
             }
        }
```

Getting error after **else** in **DialogInterface.OnClickListener()** and also at  **alert.show();** says error as **"alert cannot be resolved"**

```
 else {
                // Internet connection is not present
                // Ask user to connect to Internet
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AndroidDetectInternet.this);
                builder.setMessage("You need a network connection to use this application. Please turn on mobile network or Wi-Fi in Settings.")
                       .setTitle("No Internet Connection")
                         .setCancelable(false);
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.setButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                         //close the program
                         AndroidDetectInternet.this.finish();
               }
            });
                // Showing Alert Message
                alert.show();
             }
        }
```

What changes to be done?

Comment: import the listener you are trying to use.

Comment: Which import listener ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import DialogInterface.OnClickListener
```

instead of

```
import View.OnClickListener
```

**EDIT :**
your activity line should be:

```
... extends Activity implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener
```

Comment: when put import View.OnClickListener error "Syntax error on token "OnClickListener", ; expected after this token"

Comment: add a ';' to the import, the error clearly says it, also look at the edit

Comment: Now error getting after putting ";" as "The import View cannot be resolved"

Comment: you are supposed to import the onclick listener for a dialog and not a view. Please refer to proper java documents or sites that teach how java works and what importing means.

Comment: Please tell this code is correct or not? is it possible to add else in between two alertdialog ? and it is not working please do edit and tell new method to get worked

Answer (score 1):

Try out like this

```
       .....

      AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.setButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                         //close the program
                         AndroidDetectInternet.this.finish();
               }
            });
```